# 1347 errors in iOS SDK 4.1

Tags: xcode, sdk, ios

I had tried to build my iPhone app and got 1347 errors!
What did I do wrong?

You can download a txt file with my errors here:
http://www.mediafire.com/?jlabh2ms21z6r24

Sorry, I had to upload a file, because of limited characters...
Did any one else had the same problem and can help me?

esanits

Comment: Please describe the problems and what you've already done to try to solve them, instead of saying: "Here are my errors, please fix em."

Comment: What do you expect us to do with a text file containing a bunch of error messages?

Comment: I got the errors since I upgraded to iOS SDK 4.1... Sorry don't know how to describe them... I don't understand them

Comment: Have you checked your build info for your app to update it to build against the new SDK? (Control-click your app's build target, Get Info)

Comment: I set Base SDK to "iOS Simulator 4.1" and let iOS deployment Target "2.1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to set "iOS deployment Target" to "3.0"

Answer (score 1):

Q: How do you eat an elephant?

A: One bite at a time.

Your turn: How do you deal with 1347 errors?